# android asyncTask<String, void, void> to download file without progress and result

Tags: android, android-asynctask, extends, overriding

I want to run a task that would accept a single string and download that file from the server.
Since network related operations have to be performed on the different thread I have to extend AsyncTask. Referring the online doc I see that it takes three parameters i.e Params, Progress and Result.

I understand that it makes sense to extend a class like this

```
private class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
```

But right now I just want to download the file and not show any progress or return anything from the function.

extending a class like this gives me error

```
    private class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, void, void>
     {
       protected void doInBackground(Sting url)
       {    //code to simply download file , no progress shown , nothing returned
       }
     }
```

I also understand as an implementing class DownloadFileTask show override the method

```
protected abstract Result doInBackground (Params... params)
```

the Result in its prototype is the third parameter of AsyncTask<...> Template. So I cant have that as void. But isnt there a way to simply download file without showing progress and result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic arguments should be objects, so you should pass `Void` instead of `void`.

```
....extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
```